# Algorithm for deciding if a,b,c exist in an array so that a+b+c = z?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, element

a little stuck finding an efficient algorithm for the following problem. The algo has to decide if there are 3 elements a,b and c in an array so that a+b+c is equal to a given number z.

The naive way would be to try out the combinations, of course, but asymptotically the time needed would be too large.

For finding a and b in an array so that the sum is z is much easier. Sort the given array in ascending order and check for every element if z-a exists. But I'm not sure how I'd implement it in the 3 element problem and what time would be needed.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: a,b,c and z are integers.

Comment: Can {a,b,c} be negative?

Comment: Yes, the stipulation is only that all elements are integers.

Comment: Is this a repeating task, and if so, what is more likely to change, the array or z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is very similar to finding a and b with sum z.

First sort the array. And then fix a at position `i` and check if you have sum`z-a` in the limits `i + 1 to n`

Since you have a `O(n)` algorithm to check if a sum `z` exist with `a` and `b`. We only extend it to fix a and check if two other variable can be used to produce the sum. Giving a overall run time of `O(n^2)`

From [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/)

> ```
> // returns true if there is triplet with sum equal
> // to 'sum' present in A[]. Also, prints the triplet
> bool find3Numbers(int A[], int arr_size, int sum)
> {
>     int l, r;
>
>     /* Sort the elements */
>     sort(A, A+arr_size);
>
>     /* Now fix the first element one by one and find the
>        other two elements */
>     for (int i=0; i<arr_size-2; i++)
>     {
>
>         // To find the other two elements, start two index
>         // variables from two corners of the array and move
>         // them toward each other
>         l = i + 1; // index of the first element in the
>                    // remaining elements
>         r = arr_size-1; // index of the last element
>         while (l < r)
>         {
>             if( A[i] + A[l] + A[r] == sum)
>             {
>                 printf("Triplet is %d, %d, %d", A[i], 
>                                          A[l], A[r]);
>                 return true;
>             }
>             else if (A[i] + A[l] + A[r] < sum)
>                 l++;
>             else // A[i] + A[l] + A[r] > sum
>                 r--;
>         }
>     }
>
>     // If we reach here, then no triplet was found
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I should've written a short comment as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation for it ... So here goes nothing!

---

The best algorithm I can come up with right now is O(n^2), to explain this algorithm better we shall start with the a+b = z in O(n) case (or O(nlgn) if it wasn't sorted)

First of all, iterate {a}, and find {b} such that a+b = z. Naively if you iterate all b this would cost O(n) per {a}, leading to a O(n^2) solution. However, if you iterate {a} increasingly, the value of {b} must be strictly decreasing. We can make use of this information to reduce the time complexity as in this code:

```
for a = first element, b = last element; a != last; a = next a
while ( ( b != first element ) and (a + b > z) )
      b = previous elemnet of b
if a + b == z
      return true
```

Note that {b} only goes through the whole list once throughout loop, so it has a complexity of amortized O(n).

---

Now we can apply this principle back to the original problem, we could iterate through {a}, and apply this O(n) algorithm to {b, c} to find {z-a}, the total complexity is O(n*n = n^2).

Hopefully there is a solution with a lower complexity, I don't think O(n^2) is impressive but I just can't come up with a better one.